# How to do async tasks synchronously Android java

Tags: java, android, async-await

I have some tasks using a sdk connect to MQTT server.
So the tasks result is returned async.

```
        service.doConnect(paramVar1,new IResultListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Boolean response) {
                doSuccessConnect();
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(int statusCode, Exception exception) {
                doFailConnect();
            }
        };

        service.doFunction1(paramVar2,new IResultListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Boolean response) {
                doSuccessFunction1();
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(int statusCode, Exception exception) {
                doFailFunction1();
            }
         };


        service.doFunction2(paramVar3,new IResultListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Boolean response) {
                doSuccessFunction2();
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(int statusCode, Exception exception) {
                doFailFunction2();
            }
         };
```

I want to do tasks in order. service.doConnect※success only  -> service.doFunction1※success only -> service.doFunction2
And dont want to put service.doFunction1 in doSuccessConnect().

Can someone tell me a way to do that in Android java.
Thanks!

Comment: You can write 3 function and call next function from `success' method.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule I dont want to bind the functions together.

Comment: If the SDK does not provide an Executor parameter or does not contain any API to control or serialize execution of threads, you're gonna need to do it by yourself. Create a non-anonymous wrapper class with a boolean bIsFinished = true when callbacks are invoked. Add also a blockUntilFinished() method that waits until the boolean is set.